# Encountering TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried converting some code written by someone in Python 2 into Python 3, however it is hitting a TypeError when I try to run it.

Code:

```
text = open("C:\\Users\\Tableu\\Documents\\ICS Twitter stream\\Twitter stream\\community_tweets.txt", "r").readlines()
tweetids = re.findall("\"id\":(\d{18}),",text)
for tid in tweetids:
    count=count+1
    ff.write(str(count)+","+tid+"\n")
text0 = re.split("\n",text)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Tableu/Documents/ICS Twitter stream/Twitter stream/Cleaning.py", line 11, in <module>
    tweetids = re.findall("\"id\":(\d{18}),",text)
  File "C:\Users\Tableu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\re.py", line 222, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

This is the relevant segment of the text it is trying to read:

```
{"created_at":"Mon Sep 30 09:50:49 +0000 2019","id":1178608124464451585,"id_str":"1178608124464451585"
```

Thanks!

Comment: text is a list of strings. On line 11, re.findall takes a string but you've given it a list of strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `readlines()` function returns list of strings. I think You wanted:

```
text = "\n".join(open("C:\\Users\\Tableu\\Documents\\ICS Twitter stream\\Twitter stream\\community_tweets.txt", "r").readlines())
tweetids = re.findall("\"id\":(\d{18}),",text)
for tid in tweetids:
    count=count+1
    ff.write(str(count)+","+tid+"\n")
text0 = re.split("\n",text)
```